# How to handle the deletion of future orphan records in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, sql-delete

I have a database that is designed like this:

Tables:

```
| Snapshot |
 * id (pk)

| Detail |
 * id (pk)
 * snapshot_id (fk_delete_cascade)
 * stat1_id (fk)
 * stat2_id (fk)
 * stat3_id (fk)
 * stat4_id (fk)

| Stats |
 * id (pk)
```

The problem is that when I delete a `Snapshot`, the `details` are automatically deleted because of the `delete cascade` but related `stats` **are not** because the relation is not in the good direction (the details know the stats but not the other way around). This creates a TON of orphan records.

Is there an easy way to deal with this that I don't see or do I really need to do a query that delete the orphans `stats` afterward when they are not used by any of the 4 fields of `detail`?

Thanks!

Comment: It is hard to enforce an {1}:{1,n} relation in an RDBMS. The DBMS does {1}:{0,n}, so you can insert a Stats row, while no Detail row for it exists. Vice versa can you delete Detail rows and still keep the Stats row. So no, there is nothing to handle this out of the box for you. In Oracle, I'd either write a stored procedure for this or create a compound trigger to remove Stats rows automatically. I don't know enough about MySQL, though, to recommend some best approach here. Sorry.

Comment: If there are exactly 4 stats, simply put them in `Detail`.  ("Don't overnormalize.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to ensure consistency is to reverse the direction of reference.

Instead of making Detail have 4 fk's to Stats, create an fk in Stats referencing the Detail.

```
Stats
* id (pk)
* detail_id (fk)
```

Then you can make that fk cascading, and deleting a Detail will automatically delete all related Stats.

But this doesn't work if one Stat may be referenced by many Details. In that case, you don't have a way to automate deletion by a cascading constraint. You have to clean up orphans periodically.

```
DELETE s FROM Stats AS s LEFT OUTER JOIN Detail AS d
  ON s.id IN (d.stat1_id, d.stat2_id, d.stat3_id, d.stat4_id)
WHERE d.id IS NULL;
```

Unfortunately, this is impossible to optimize because of the multiple columns in Detail. It must do a very expensive table-scan to try to find related Detail rows.

So if you can reverse the fk reference like I described above, that would be better.